# Picture Library Slideshow Webpart

Tags: picture-library

Can we use root site collection picture library path in other site collection picture library slideshow OOTB webpart? I have picture library created in root site collection and i want to use the same path in other site collection for slideshow webpart which is available OOTB. but that webpart only takes picture library created within that site collection only. Any trick for solving this?

Comment: Don't have SP to test, but can you configure anywhere full links to the pictures? Can you see, once adding the pictures to be shown, any document folders located on a (globally) shared location?